# MySQL-server problematic

Tags: server, apt, mysql, 16.10

I installed MySQL with the command `sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client`, and then I entered `/etc/init.d/mysql start`. My problem occurred when I entered `mysql`. The error was displayed on the screen : `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`.

I tried to remove (with `remove` and `purge`) and reinstall `mysql-server` and `mysql-client`, but it doesn't work. It seems removing a package removes all packaged data, but leaves usually small (modified) user configuration files behind, in case the remove was an accident. Just issuing an installation request for the accidentally removed package will restore its function as before in that case.

I would like to obtain such following image : [image]

Could anyone be able to help me at this point?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing it you probably provided a password for the root user (there should be a dialog asking for it), so in order to use the mysql client you would typically run the following command

```
mysql -u root -p
```

where -u is the user you want to use and -p is and indication to mysql to show you a prompt asking for root's password.

For your second part of your question, if you want to completely remove mysql you should first remove the packages

```
sudo apt purge mysql-server
```

but before reinstalling, you need also to delete the `/var/lib/mysql` and everything under it.

Comment: With the command `alias mysql='mysql -u root -p'`, that's work perfectly.